# Where is engineer Watson?

Tags: full-of-stars

I've managed to successfully reach the blue sector 3 times now, and I have about 75 colonists there. However, to upgrade the shelter there to level 2, I need to find engineer Watson. You can find her location by spending 20 idium crystals, but every time I get to the blue sector I am just short by a small amount.

So where is engineer Watson found, and how to I get her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found, without paying the idium crystals, that engineer Watson can be found by visiting Arcadia 1. Once here, your compute will tell you that there is somebody on the planet called engineer Watson that is crucial to the survival of the human race.

Then when talking to the tourists, you have to ask to see Watson. Then simply tell her what the computer said, and her along with the other 11 tourists will board your ship for the journey back to the home world.

It is then necessary to reach the blue sector, in order for the settlement to reach the next level.